# pyspark error when trying to show() simple data frame

Tags: pyspark, pip, anaconda

I have just installed pyspark 3.5.0 and when running the following code:

```
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

i get the following error:

```
24/02/19 11:41:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 26 more
24/02/19 11:41:39 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
```

I tried installing pyspark from anaconda and from pip, but i get the same error. Has anybody encountered this same behaviour?

Comment: are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: no, i'm running it locally. i installed pyspark using miniconda

Comment: Insufficient memory allocation can sometimes cause Python workers to crash. Ensure your system has enough memory to run `PySpark`, and consider adjusting memory settings in Spark if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling Anaconda and creating a new environment the error didn't appear anymore and the expected results appeared.